# Syntax Error in UserFriendshipsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax, controller, syntax-error

I am getting a SyntaxError in UserFriendshipsController#index for:

@user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.all

I am not sure what I missed. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated! I'm still new to rails. Thanks in advance!

**Controller**

```
 class UserFriendshipsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate_user!

   def index
     @user_friendships = current_user.user_friendships.all
   end

   def accept
      @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params [:id])
      if @user_friendship.accept!
       flash[:success] = "You are now friends with #{@user_friendship.friend.name}"
     else
       flash[:error] = "That friendship could not be accepted"
      redirect_to user_friendships_path
   end

   def new
     if params[:friend_id]
       @friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
       @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
     else
       flash[:error] = "Friend required"
     end
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
     render file: 'public/404', status: :not_found
   end

   def create
     if params[:user_friendship] && params[:user_friendship].has_key?(:friend_id)
       @friend = User.find(params[:user_friendship][:friend_id])
       @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
       if @user_friendship.save
         flash[:success] = "You are now friends!"
       else
         flash[:error] = "There was a problem."
       end
       redirect_to user_path(@friend)
     else
       flash[:error] = "Friend required"
       redirect_to root_path
     end
   end

   def edit
   end

 end
 end
```

**Index**

```
     <% @user_Friendships.each do |friendship| %>
          <% friend = friendship.friend %>
      <div id="<%= dom_id(friendship) %>" class="friend row">
       <div class="span1">
        <center><%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)), user %></center>
       </div>
       <div class="span7">
         <strong><%= friend.name %></strong><br />
            <%if friendship.pending? %>
            <em>Frienship is pending.</em> <%=link_to "Delete request", edit_user_friendship_path(friendship) %>.
            <% end %>
            <% if friendship.requested? %>
                <em>Friendship requested.</em> <%= link_to "Accept Friendship", edit_user_friendship_path(friendship) %>.
            <% end %>
            <% if friendship.accepted? %>
                <em>Friendship started <%= friendship.updated_at %>.</em> <%= link_to "Update friendship", edit_user_friendship_path(friendship) %>.
            <% end %>
           </div>
       </div>
   <% end %>
```

**Model**

```
     class UserFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'

     attr_accessible :user_id, :friend_id, :user, :friend :state

     state_machine :state, initial: :pending do

    after_transition on: :accept, do: :send_acceptance_email

    state :requested

    event :accept do
        transition any => :accepted
    end
   end

   def self.request(user1, user2)
    transaction do
        friendship1 = create!(user: user1, friend: user2, state: 'pending')
        friendship2 = create!(user: user2, friend: user1, state: 'requested')

        friendship1.send_request_email
     end
```

Comment: `@user_friendship` != `@user_Friendships`, but you'll probably need to include the complete stack trace.

Comment: please make sure that you have closed `class` declaration with `end` keyword. And show the whole controller's file

Comment: I tried @ user_friendship != @ user_Friendships however, now I'm getting a NoMethod Error in UserFriendships#index for:<% @user_Friendships.each do |friendship| %>
Thank you.

Comment: @Dena that says that `@user_Friendships` is `nil` or just non-enumerator

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Thank you for your help. I finally got it working with yours and everyones input.

Answer (score 0):

In your index file, you use @user_Friendships which is not the same variable as the one defined in your controller @user_friendship (extra s and capital F).

Comment: That isn't, however, a syntax error; you'd just have a `nil`.

Comment: @Kyle I am getting a NoMethodError in UserFriendship#Index for the same thing. nil:NilClass now. What's the best way to fix this? I have tried using the same lower case and upper case within my index and controller however, I still get an error. Thanks

Comment: And you removed/and or added that extra s?

Comment: Can you also post your user model?